# CSS Tables in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good morning!

I'm currently designing a website with bootstrap. I used the table-responsive to create a table. I customised the table but i can't remove the gray underline?

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Track Name</th>
      <th>Requested</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Remotion (Original Mix)</p><p><small><span class="grey_color">by</span> Ovaal</small></p></td>
      <td>1 day ago</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary"><small>Waiting for Approval</small></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Remotion (Original Mix)</p><p><small><span class="grey_color">by</span> Ovaal</small></p></td>
      <td>1 day ago</td>
      <td><span class="label label-primary"><small>Waiting for Approval</small></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I tried adding margin-top to tbody as well as adding margin-bottom to thead. Nothing works.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Will you be able to create a fiddle?

Comment: underline?? which underline? are you talking about borders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to override the relevant rules in `boostrap.css` - e.g.

```
.table thead > tr > th, 
.table tbody > tr > th, 
.table tfoot > tr > th, 
.table thead > tr > td, 
.table tbody > tr > td, 
.table tfoot > tr > td {
    border: none; 
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/403/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
table tr{border: none;}
```

Cheers

Comment: That's not specific enough for it to override Bootstrap.